# How do I split a string in a SWIG template?

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, swig-template

I have a SWIG template in my web app where I am rendering the value of a score with a decimal value. Like this:

[image]

I am using Angular filters to break apart the number into the whole number and the decimal number. BUT in another one of my server templates I am not using Angular and need to rely only on SWIG to display the number values. How can I do some sort of javascript String.split operation on the server via SWIG?

```
<span class="ng-binding">
    {{ wine.scoreTotal }}
    <sup class="ng-binding">
        {{ wine.ScoreTotal }}
    </sup>
</span>
```

I see some filters in the SWIG documentation but didn't see a way to do a SPLIT filter. Is there a way to do inline Javascript string operation like so?

```
<span class="ng-binding">
    {% String(wine.ScoreTotal).split('.')[0] %}
    <sup class="ng-binding">
        .{% String(wine.ScoreTotal).split('.')[1] %}
    </sup>
</span>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was pretty close. I changed the {%  %} to {{ }} like so:

```
<span class="ng-binding">
    {{ String(wine.ScoreTotal).split('.')[0] }}
    <sup class="ng-binding">
        .{{ String(wine.ScoreTotal).split('.')[1] }}
    </sup>
</span>
```

This did the trick.

Comment: Exactly. You are working on a String object. which provides the split function. Please adjust your 'snippet', since it shows the copied code from your question, rather than the corrected one.